# Android simple program interest calculator

Tags: java, android, xml, calculator

I am in the very first lessons of programming for Android and for my first attempt I tried to develop an interest calculator. The app starts but then crashes. The code follows:

```
package com.example.vitor.precojusto;

import  com.example.vitor.precojusto.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SICalculatorActivity extends Activity {


    private TextView PA;
    private TextView Interest_Rate;
    private TextView Years;
    private EditText PA_bar;
    private EditText IR_bar;
    private SeekBar  year_bar;
    private Button   calculate;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sicalculator);

        PA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PA);
        Interest_Rate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Interest_Rate);
        Years= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Years);
        PA_bar= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PA_bar);
        IR_bar= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IR_bar);
        year_bar=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.year_bar);
        calculate=(Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);

        calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){


            }
        });
    }

}
```

sicalculator.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    tools:context=".SICalculatorActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Years"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/IR_bar"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="2 Year(s)"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/year_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Years"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Years"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/year_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/year_bar"
        android:text="Calculate" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/IR_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Years"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Interest_Rate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/IR_bar"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/IR_bar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="Interest Rate"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/PA_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Principal Amount"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/PA_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Interest_rate"
        android:layout_below="@+id/PA"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Do you guys have any guess why the app crashes? I tried to run it on an emulation of nexus on Android Studio (Android 5.0 Lollipop).

Comment: add the stack trace of the crash to your question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to change your manifest.xml to declare this activity as the main one.

```
<activity android:name=".SICalculatorActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Dont forget to post the stacktrace, you can find it in the Android Monitor, and it shows the error that happened.